# Should we merge the tags [masm32] and [masm64] into [masm]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

There are only 14 questions that have the [masm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm64) tag, most of them also have the [masm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm) tag. There are 499 questions in the [masm32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm32) tag, 257 of them contain the [masm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm) tag

Both [masm32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm32) and [masm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm64) seem redundant, because they're already accompanied by the [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86), [x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-64) or [64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/64-bit) tags so it's clear which platform the OP's talking about. There's no need for the bitness in masm so IMO we should merge those into [masm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm)

Comment: Additional info: not every question with one of the `masm` tags has an architecture tag, so these would need to be added.  They are distinct assemblers (`ml` and `ml64`), with corresponding differences in supported command line options and assembly language.  The `masm32` tag info is for something else entirely (not the Microsoft Assembler). `masm64` has no tag info and few questions.

Comment: They are SDK names.  The masm32.com web site is very popular, they did an excellent job.

Answer (score 2):

As someone with deep familiarity in the subject area, I've declined this proposal. As Hans Passant said in a comment, these are SDK names. They don't merely indicate that someone is targeting x86-32 or x86-64 using the Microsoft Assembler (MASM), but rather they refer to the [MASM32 SDK](https://www.masm32.com/), which includes a *lot* more than just the assembler:

> The MASM32 SDK is an independent project that is designed to ease the entry of experienced programmers into the field of assembler language programming. It is a complex and demanding form of programming that requires high coding precision and a good understanding of both the Intel mnemonics and x86 processor architecture as it is utilised by the Windows operating system environment but for the effort, it offers flexibility and performance that is beyond the best of compilers when a high enough level of expertise is reached.

This distinction is called out in the [masm32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm32) tag wiki excerpt:

> The MASM32 packet is a working development environment (SDK) for programmers who are interested in either learning or writing 32 bit Microsoft assembler (MASM).

The full tag wiki says essentially the same thing, but adds a link. (And some incorrect grammar, which I've now corrected.)

Questions that assume the MASM32 environment won't necessarily be answerable by those whose expertise is limited to Microsoft's Assembler (MASM). From the MASM32 website:

> The range of macros to automate tasks in MASM is almost unlimited…

Those "unlimited" macros aren't standard MASM keywords or opcodes. It might as well be an entirely different language. Furthermore, having separate tags gives everyone the ability to filter questions according to their interests.

There is also a release of the MASM32 SDK specifically for 64-bit targets, which is called [MASM64](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=6486.0).

In the case of the [masm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm64) tag, many of the questions were *misusing* the tag, so I've corrected those with a manual retagging. (An automatic merge wouldn't have been appropriate, and the [masm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm64) tag should continue to exist.) I've also updated the tag wiki to match the [masm32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm32) tag.